Contacting interviewer prior to interview for advice/clarification
New grad trudging through job-search routine. I have an important interview coming up and I've been told who is interviewing me. It's for quite a small company (<50 employees). The interview invite just tells me there will be a case study. Now I'm familiar with case studies for consulting but this is slightly different and people online seem to disagree wrt to what the case study means in this context. Is it totally inappropriate to message the interviewer (senior analyst at the company for what it's worth) to ask for general advice and some clarification? I feel that depending on the person receiving the message, it could be seen as proactive and confident, wanting to cover bases and do my best to be fully informed, but could also be seen as insecure, unaware, and even a bit dumb. Any suggestions or feedback would be appreciated

This is a "should I?" question in a minimal disguise.

Yeah it is, i wasnt trying to hide that. Is that not allowed here or?

@justsomeguy123 generally it is off-topic to solicit advice about choices - from the Tour section, "Personal advice on what to do" is noted as off-topic. That being said I think this question is more about whether messaging an upcoming interviewer is out of bounds in general, as opposed to whether it would be out of bounds in your specific circumstance. So I think its fine.

The question is definitely able to be phrased in a way that keeps in on topic, I agree. I was pointing out that the current phrasing flirts with a reason for closure.


Is it totally inappropriate to message the interviewer (senior analyst
at the company for what it's worth) to ask for general advice and some
clarification?

Yes, it's totally inappropriate.
If they wanted to coach you up before the interview, they would have arranged to do so.

ok thanks. What about contacting someone who is doing the role I'm applying for at the company for advice? it's quite a small firm so could easily get around to the interviewer that i did so but i feel this isnt 'cheating' or anything

@justsomeguy123, Honestly, you should have done that before even applying. But now, it seems like you're trying to cheat. Have you asked the HR person for more information?

I wouldn't contact your interviewer if you have questions about the interview process. Instead, I'd direct the questions toward the person you've been in contact with for setting up your interviews, likely a recruiter or someone in the HR department. As someone who has been an interviewer, conducting interviews is an activity on top of my daily work, and interviewers often don't have time to field questions, even if they are questions that can or should be answered. Part of the job of the recruiter or the HR team is to guide candidates through the interviewing process. If a question needs an answer from the hiring manager or an interviewer, they can coordinate getting that answer.
However, I'm also not sure what is confusing about the idea of a case study or what "this context" is. I would expect most interviewees to understand what a case study is, so receiving a question along those lines could be detrimental.

And what do you think asking a new grad about a case study looks like?

@mxyzplk I don't understand the question. A case study is a well-defined concept. Unless the asker wants to clarify why they are confused about a case study in this particular context, I would expect any interviewee, including a new grad, to understand what one is. Asking the question would likely be detrimental, but I can't say without more details.

Me, Personally, I always value people who go above and beyond to achieve the result they are wanting.
So, if someone finds my work email address or deduces it from publicly available information - that is something that I feel shows initiative, a bit of sleuthing and other personal attributes that I find tend to translate well into my field of work (IT).
BUT!
It is a High-Risk, High-reward strategy. Some people will look upon it as quasi-cheating. Some will look upon it as disrespectful etc.
I cannot make the decision for you - but I will say this: If you do decide to contact them, couch in terms of:

You want to prepare yourself for success
You are keen on working for this company
You are new to the job market and so are looking for every advantage you can get.

The last part is more so that if the person interviewing is not like me, they will look favourably upon it as a Faux pas and let it slide as an over-exurberance of youth.

It's a coin flip. It might help, but it might hurt.
Keep in mind even if a company uses a term like "case study" that doesn't mean that all case studies are conducted the same way. Asking the internet won't get you clarity.
You have done research, so look at the differing explanations and use that to understand what you might face in the broadest terms.
This shouldn't be your only application, so use the experience to help you in future interviews.
